# Cloud computing application

Tags: reference-request, applications

**Question**

I want to analyze the potential of a cloud computing application that performs payroll and invoicing over the Internet from a large Internet company.I want also to describe the systems development
steps and procedures you would use to analyze the feasibility of this approach.

> I would like to find material and sources regarding the above task (lecture notes,similar exercises)

I have generall knowledge of cloud computing but i want to know more about this application(cloud computing for the use of payroll)

Thanks in advance

Comment: This sounds too broad to me. "How do I approach a complex system?" is probably not something that will have a simple answer.  Any community votes?

Comment: i need general information adout the cloudpayroll application

Comment: Cross-posted: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65483020/781723.  Please do not post your question on multiple sites.